# What is <<= operator in C++

Tags: c++, windows

I found following code in a legacy system.As it seems to be a "assign and left shift" but I see this code is copying a string to ws but I couldn't understand how ? I wonder if simple assignment would have been enough to copy one string to another then why someone would code like this ?

```
vector<string> unique_dirs; 
......
......
......

std::wstring ws;
ws <<= unique_dirs[i];
```

Edit - I looked at the class implementation (c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xstring) . There is no such operator "<<=" overloaded in the class.

Comment: It is indeed std::wstring and this code is in use for years..

Comment: @CharlesBailey Given the presence of `vector` and `string` as well without the `std::`, I suspect that it _is_ the standard `std::wstring`.  To which someone has added additional overloaded operators, which I'm not certain is legal (and which is certainly very bad practice if it is legal).

Comment: @Rahul Maybe because of [this overload](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/basic_string/operator%3C%3C/)?

Comment: OK, in that case how is `<<=` defined because it must be implemented in the legacy source code in a nearby namespace.

Comment: @Leri: but that has nothing to do with `<<=`.

Comment: @CharlesBailey I have pretty limited knowledge of C++ so won't argue. Logically, it may be insertion and assignment result of insertion. But once again, I am just guessing.

Comment: @Rahul without the overload of `<<=` this question has no clear answer -1, also you could debug the code and see where it goes...

Comment: As you're using Visual Studio, why don't you just run the code in the debugger, stick a breakpoint at the `<<=` line, and step into the function to see what actually gets run? It would be easier than people guessing.

Comment: wxWidgets used to add this operator abuse (not sure if they still do nowadays). Personally, I hate it when operators do weird, unintuitive things just to make code look "cool".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite my comment that investigating the code would be easier than people guessing what is happening, here is my guess at a possible implementation, as you were wondering *how* it could be done - this could appear anywhere in the code, pretty much, providing it can be seen where it is being called, as it's not modifying any of the standard library classes:

```
std::wstring& operator<<=(std::wstring& out, const std::string& in) {
    out += std::wstring(in.begin(), in.end());
    return out;
}
```

My *guess* here is that as a `string` is being passed to a `wstring`, the operator is performing some kind of "widening" (a poor-mans conversion from `char` to `wchar`, disregarding encoding).

Why would you want this rather than using a straight assignment?  Well, aside from `ws = unique_dirs[i];` being a compilation error, it could provide you with a method of concatenating strings:

```
std::string hello("hello ");
std::string goodbye("goodbye");
std::wstring ws;

ws <<= hello;
ws <<= goodbye;
// ws now is L"hello goodbye"
```

---

As an aside, the above does not modify the standard library - it is not extending the `std::basic_string` class, it's simply providing an operator that takes two classes as parameters.  So I'm not sure how it comes under "legality" with regards its usage.  It is fairly horrific, however, and its usage is morally reprehensible.

Comment: Ah! I found an overloaded implementation of this method since it is declared as inline so couldn't see during debug. I searched it earlier multiple times but couldn't find. This time I was lucky. It does some little more in addition to icabod  mentioned in this post.

Comment: @Rahul: I'm now curious to know what else it actually does... :)

Answer (score 3):

There is no such standard overload operator the left operand of which is std::wstring and the right operand is std::string. You should investigate the code where this operator was encountered that to find its definition.

Answer (score 2):

By default :

```
ws <<= unique_dirs[i]
```

is the same as :

```
ws = ws << unique_dirs[i]
```

It is simply the Bitwise left shift assignment.
But in this case, it should be overloaded to work with strings.

Comment: It depends on who defined `<<=` and how. There is no "default" implementation of `<<=` for objects of class type.

Comment: Given that `ws` is a "user defined type", `ws <<= x` is most certainly _not_ the same as `ws = ws << x`.  (Hopefully, if they're both defined, the results will be the same, but a different overloaded function will still be called.)

Comment: And of course, in C++, `<<` is the insertion operator (although for historical reasons, it still means left shift when applied to integral types).

Comment: I know it expends to leftshift assignment as  mentioned that in my question but I am sure this code copies the string ws. My question is how is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Unless the <<= is overloaded, It is the bitwise left shift operator.

ws <<= unique_dirs[i]
means
ws = ws << unique_dirs[i]

Although I am doubtful about the logic behind how the code is using some string element in the vector for this purpose.

Comment: `ws <<= unique_dirs[i]` does _not_ mean `ws = ws << unique_dirs[i]`.  That relationship only happens if the types involved are integral types.  And anyone inconsequent enough to overload `<<` for `std::wstring` is probably inconsequent enough to give `<<=` a totally unrelated meaning.

Comment: @JamesKanze  Correct. We are trying to decipher the right meaning of it.